# JSP form select bind with map

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jsp, el

I am trying to bind a map element to choosen value from JSP. Elements of select are comming from different map, but keySets are same in both maps.

Part of java code :

```
private Map<String, List<String>> customCriteriaMap = new HashMap<>();
private Map<String, String> activeCustomCriteria = new HashMap<>();
```

So for example:
customCriteriaMap have 1 entry:

```
key: International, value: list contains: true, false
```

activeCriteriaMap have alsoe 1 entry:

```
kry: International, value: true
```

Now after choosing false on select and submiting form i would like to have entry in activeCriteriaMap:

```
key: International, value: false
```

Jsp code:

```
<div class="grid_6 two">
    <c:forEach items="${settingsForm.customCriteria}" var="actualCriteriaValues">
        <c:set var="actualCriteriaKey" value="${actualCriteriaValues.key}" />
        <c:set var="activeCriteria" value="${settingsForm.activeCustomCriteria[actualCriteriaKey]}"/>
        <label>Criteria:</label>
        <form:select path="activeCustomCriteria[${actualCriteriaKey}]" >
            <c:forEach items="${actualCriteriaValues.value}" var="actualCriteriaValue">
                <c:set var="optionLabel" value="${actualCriteriaValue}"/>
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${optionLabel eq 'N'}">
                        <c:set var="optionLabel" value="False"/>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:when test="${optionLabel eq 'Y'}">
                        <c:set var="optionLabel" value="True"/>
                    </c:when>
                </c:choose>
                <form:option value="${actualCriteriaValue}" label="${optionLabel}"/>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:select>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

Values in activeCustomCriteria do not change after selecting different value from select and submit. It is always same - default value.

Thanks in advance,
Marek.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

This peace of code works just fine, problem was in one of Interceptors. Still this code may be trated as example how to use one map to fill select nad other one to bind :)